# Delete from DCIM directory?

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I've made an app which modifies photos taken that are saved to the DCIM directory.

I'd now like to delete the original version of the photo.

AndroidManifex:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

There's a warning here for external storage saying this permission no longer provides write access. So on launch my app requests that permission from the user:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_BY_LOAD_PROFILE);
```

Here is the code for deleting original photo:

```
File inFile = new File(mediaItem.Directory, mediaItem.FileName);
if (inFile.exists()) {
    try {
        inFile.delete();

            context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{ mediaItem.Directory + mediaItem.FileName } );
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        
    }
}
```

I have tried both `File.delete()` and `context.getContentResolver().delete()`, neither of them seem to actually delete the file, and no error is ever thrown.

Comment: An Android 11 device?

Comment: Yes, Android 11

Comment: And the original file is not created by your app.

Comment: Well no, it's the original photos taken from the camera app. My app uses a worker which gets triggered when new photo is taken.

Comment: Well under Android 11 the owner of the file is important. If you are not the owner then write/delete is not possible.

Comment: How are apps like Google Files able to delete duplicates and such then? Would I be able to delete files if the user is prompted? (I think I would use an intent for this? I'm new to android development)

Comment: Those apps requested permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest. And such.